# ООП Python. Индексация списка в методе класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, методы

```py
from copy import deepcopy

class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, m):
        self.matrix = deepcopy(m)

    def __add__(self, other):
        sumMatrix = []
        for i in range(len(self.matrix)):
            tempMatrix = []
            for x, y in zip(self.matrix[i], other[i]):
                tempMatrix.append(x + y)
            sumMatrix.append(tempMatrix)
        return sumMatrix
```

Необходимо реализовать класс Matrix. Он должен содержать:
1) Конструктор от списка списков. Гарантируется, что списки состоят из чисел, не пусты и все имеют одинаковый размер. Конструктор должен копировать содержимое списка списков, т. е. при изменении списков, от которых была сконструирована матрица, содержимое матрицы изменяться не должно.
2) метод **add**, принимающий вторую матрицу того же размера и возвращающий сумму матриц.

Вопрос: когда реализую метод **add** (нужно получить список сумм списков),

```py
m1 = Matrix([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
m2 = Matrix([[0, 1, 0], [20, 0, -1], [-1, -2, 0]])
print(m1 + m2)
```

то получаю ошибку, что класс 'Matrix' не индексируемый, хотя подается список списков по моей логике.

```py
TypeError: 'Matrix' object does not support indexing
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема и как ее решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
for x, y in zip(self.matrix[i], other[i]):
```

на

```
for x, y in zip(self.matrix[i], other.matrix[i]):
```

Т.к. other у вас - это тоже Matrix, а он сам по себе не является списком списков, он только **содержит** в себе этот список списков в атрибуте `.matrix`, и к этому атрибуту нужно обратиться явно.

Ну, либо можно реализовать дандер-метод `__getitem__` и тогда ваш Matrix будет сам по себе уметь возвращать результат по индексу, но в рамках данной задачи в такой доработке мало смысла.

И, кстати, в текущем варианте у вас `__add__` ничего не возвращает. Так что сложить-то он сложит, но этот результат никуда не попадает, и ваш принт напечатает None. Так что добавьте туда `return`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Все работает!